# Allow outside networks to connect to my SMTP server

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have a simple python SMTP email server that will only work for devices on my network (**using 127.0.0.1 as the host**).

I was wondering what I would need in order to make this accessible to **remote networks**. (if possible in python)

Thanks!

Comment: What library/module are you using to make this server?

Comment: [smtplib - python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)

Comment: Solution up. @eeevvv1122333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

What worked for me was to change this line of code.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
```

change this line of code to your IP address with the port that you want to connect to. For example Google.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
```

If you are hosting this server though then you will need to port forward your IP on your router and then give your friends or whoever is connecting to you your IP.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("YOUR IP",PORT FORWARDED)
server = smtplib.SMTP("192.168.1.15",8080)
```